# how to determine the server port in MINA

Tags: java, nio, java-io

in my application i have a server that listen in more than one udp port. i used MINA in this application.

```
// code looks like this.
NioDatagramAcceptor acceptor = new NioDatagramAcceptor();
...
...
acceptor.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9911));
acceptor.bind(new InetSocketAddress(9912));
```

now in handler when i receive the data i have following code.

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message)
        throws Exception {
    if (message instanceof IoBuffer) {
        String msg = "data received in port "+ <NEED TO GET THE PORT NO>;
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

in the code i have no idea how to get the port no ( 9911 or 9912 in this case) in which the data is received.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/apidocs/org/apache/mina/core/session/IoSession.html

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message)
    throws Exception {
if (message instanceof IoBuffer) {
    InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress = (InetSocketAddress) session.getServiceAddress();
    int portNumber = inetSocketAddress.getPortNumber();
    String msg = "data received in port "+ portNumber;
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

Comment: thanks. it worked. by the way, i was manage to solve it by using getLocalAddress(). but it seems your way is the perfect one. thank you very much.